# I'm getting a "Promise resolved while context is inactive" error when I try save a setting on a webextension addon settings page on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to implement a settings page in my add-on using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Implement_a_settings_page
Code (copied from their example, minor things changed):

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Posture Promoter - with Emma Watson",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": { "128": "emma_icon.png" },
  "description": "Want better posture? Want to maintain a healthier back? Emma Watson will remind you every 30 minutes to sit straight!",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "settings.html"
  },
"permissions": ["tabs","storage"],
"browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "addon@someaddon.com"
    }
  }
}
```

background.js

```
 var getting = browser.storage.local.get("interval").then(
 function(e){
   var time = 1000 * 60 * (e.interval || 30);
   window.setInterval(test, time);
 });

function test() {
  var popupURL = browser.extension.getURL("emma.html"); 
  var emmaWindow = browser.windows.create({
    url: popupURL,
    type: "popup",
    width: 680,
    height: 710
   });
}
```

emma.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <img src="emma.png" width=650/>
</body>
</html>
```

settings.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <style>
  p{font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;}
  </style>
  <body>
      <form>
          <p>Remind me to fix posture in</p>
          <input type="number" id="posture"> 
          <p>minutes.</p>
          <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
      <script src="options.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

options.js

```
function saveOptions(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  browser.storage.local.set({
    interval: document.getElementById('posture').value
  }).then(function(e) {
    restoreOptions(); //just to check setting is saved
    browser.runtime.reload();
  });
}

function restoreOptions() {

  function setCurrentChoice(result) {
    document.getElementById('posture').value = result.interval || 30;
  }

  function onError(error) {
    console.log("Error:",error);
  }

  let getting = browser.storage.local.get("interval");
  getting.then(setCurrentChoice, onError);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", restoreOptions);
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", saveOptions);
```

Every time I click the save button `I get Promise resolved while context is inactive` at line 3 in options.js
I know that background.js without settings works, so the problem isn't there.
I'm using Firefox 83.0 on Windows 10 1909.
The reason I asked the question is the other similar questions don't apply to Firefox 57 or newer.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for your help, edited code. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the form from also doing a postback:

```js
function saveOptions(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```